# How can I make live search in my site like wikipedia?

Tags: javascript, ajax, backend, software-design

I want to add such a search bar in my site that users search my site and they can get instant result though live search like wikipedia. How can be done this job?

Comment: watch the devtool's network tab while you type in a search; it shows you the parts you need.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is an ajax request which queries a php file and search for the keyword in your db and return the topic to be displayed as search predictions. Here is a good example that you can try it out.

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, you need an endpoint that you can call each time you change the input with the current results. That endpoint would then spit back out search results which you could render to show the user.